# Can't create a new class from pointer element in array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, class-constructors

I have an array of my class type "Room". There are two constructors for Room, a default and a custom. I want to call a specific constructor when initializing elements of my Room array. Neither default or custom works. I'm getting this error:

No operator "=" matches these operands, operand types are Room = Room*

Here's my code:

btw rooms is a Room pointer type

```
void RoomManager::createRooms()
{
    rooms = new Room[numOfRooms];

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRooms; i++)
    {
       rooms[i] = new Room();
    }
}`
```

How should I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: `rooms` needs to be defined as an array of `Room *` (pointers to `Room` objects). So your code should look like: `rooms = new Room *[numOfRooms];` Declare `rooms` like: `Room **rooms;`

Answer (score 0):

At first, there is no reason to call default constructor in your cycle, c++ already did it for you when allocating array.
But if you want create an array and initialize its elements with custom constructor call, you can use placement new operator

```
#include <new>

// ...

void RoomManager::createRooms()
{
    rooms = static_cast<Room*>(operator new[](numOfRooms * sizeof(Room)));

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRooms; i++)
    {
       new &(rooms[i]) Room();
    }
}
```

And if you use placement new, you must manually call destructor at the end of program:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRooms; i++)
    {
       rooms[i].~Room();
    }
    operator delete[](rooms);
```

Comment: Ah k fair enough. You're method looks good. I'll give it a try.

Comment: You're method is returning some errors. Trying to assign rooms to a * void

Answer (score 0):

Cause of error:

`rooms` is an array of `Room`. To each element of `rooms`OP assigns a pointer to `Room`, `Room *`. `Room` and `Room *` are not compatible, so he compiler cannot generate code for the assigment.

Solution:

Fortunately, there is no need for the assignment at all. `rooms = new Room[numOfRooms]` allocated and default constructed all of your rooms for you.

```
void RoomManager::createRooms()
{
    rooms = new Room[numOfRooms];
}
```

In addition is is questionable that you want to allocate rooms this way. When `numOfRooms` is set, you call allocate right after and save yourself an extra function.

An even better route is to consider using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).